# Parsing and analysing the Receipts using OCR

Tags: parsing, ocr

I'm working a project where the receipts can be read using OCR and parsing it to get the important information like merchant name, date, amount etc. I'm using the [vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) provided by the google to parse an image and get the text out of it in JSON format. Now I want to go to the next step where I can parse the text and try to identify the information by it location or expressions.Right now I'm able to extract the amount from the simple currency followed by number string. From this point where should I looking for analysing the text to extract any information(Trying to develop a system that can extract info from any type of receipts). Even a small lead will help me to go forward.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started extracting information from the returned text format by looking for tokens like "Date" , "Amount" , "total" , "Rs". I have developed an algorithm which rank the different number found as actual amount. Also I'm getting the Merchant name which in most of the cases be on the top of the receipt  by removing tokens like ("the","in" , "welcome" ) etc.

Comment: Currently, I'm on this case too. Can  you explain more about your rank algorithm? @sandy

Comment: Hi @DharmaSaputra, I was using the regular expression for string to check whether it forms amount. Such string closest to the key words like "Total" , "amount" was given higher rank.